# Minecraft Server Ubuntu 16.10 - Cant Connect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have set up Minecraft servers on Windows in the past and was able to connect to them externally no problem. However, after setting it up on Ubuntu it is absolutely refusing to allow external connections.

```
sudo ufw status
25565                      ALLOW       Anywhere                                   
25565 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)


netstat -ntlp | grep 25565 
tcp6       0      0 0.0.0.0:25565           :::*                    LISTEN      3228/java 


$ sudo iptables -L --line-numbers | grep 25565
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:25565
2    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:25565
```

I have port forwarded my router on tcp 25565 to my ip address, and yet I am still unable to see myself on canyouseeme.org for 25565 using public ip address.

Minecraft server.properties:

```
#Minecraft server properties
#Tue Apr 11 00:00:54 MDT 2017
max-tick-time=60000
generator-settings=
force-gamemode=false
allow-nether=true
gamemode=0
enable-query=false
player-idle-timeout=0
difficulty=1
spawn-monsters=true
op-permission-level=4
announce-player-achievements=true
pvp=true
snooper-enabled=true
level-type=DEFAULT
hardcore=false
enable-command-block=false
max-players=20
network-compression-threshold=256
resource-pack-sha1=
max-world-size=29999984
server-port=25565
server-ip=
spawn-npcs=true
allow-flight=false
level-name=world
view-distance=10
resource-pack=
spawn-animals=true
white-list=false
generate-structures=true
online-mode=true
max-build-height=256
level-seed=
use-native-transport=true
enable-rcon=false
motd=A Minecraft Server
```

Anyone have any ideas on what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: Everything *looks* fine so all I can think of is your network firewall. Double check if you have port forwarded to the correct local IP and that that is the only :25565/TCP rule open on the firewall. You should only forward one port per ip so traffic goes to the correct place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello anyone searching this question, the answer I found is this:

As I was running a wireless router connected to a non-wifi router, I first needed to route incoming 25565 traffic from the non-wifi router to the ip of the WiFi router that the minecraft server was connected to. Then on my WiFi router I routed the 25565 packets to the ip of the connected minecraft server.